# Features extraction methods

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction

Which *methods/algorithms* that can be used to extract the features from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6hQZ.jpg)

[image]

Where the previous image is a linear combination of several images with different weights

i.e., `image= w1×LP01 + w2×LP02 + w3×LP03 + w4×LP11 + w5×LP12` ...etc

The LPmn images are something  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRh3r.png),

[image]
`w` is the weight.

I am looking for other methods except linear regression based methods, e.g., *PCA, LDA, SVD* ...

I have tried to use wavelet transform but it doesn't work. **Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 0):

I would have played by reshaping the image to a vector and use the entire vector as your feature. And use a simple neural network to see how that works out. For a start!

Finding feature is an iterative process. It is not always obvious!